# ANOVA results differ between output and APAtables function in R

Tags: r, anova

So I conducted a two-way ANOVA in R. I looked at the output with the summary function everything was fine, it did tell me that 136 cases were deleted. However, when I want to transfer my results to a table with the function *apa.aov.table(anova)* the table shows me different values and different significance

so my question is why? and how can I transfer the same values from my output?
[image]

**APATables version:**

```
ANOVA results using Alz_20 as the dependent variable
 

      Predictor      SS   df     MS       F    p partial_eta2 CI_90_partial_eta2
    (Intercept)  636.68    1 636.68 1630.08 .000                                
         Aalter    1.56    2   0.78    1.99 .136          .00         [.00, .00]
          Ajp40   60.28    4  15.07   38.58 .000          .03         [.02, .04]
 Aalter x Ajp40    9.96    8   1.25    3.19 .001          .01         [.00, .01]
          Error 1966.20 5034   0.39                                             

Note: Values in square brackets indicate the bounds of the 90% confidence interval for partial eta-squared
```

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: It looks to me that your R version doesn't include an intercept term, but you haven't provided your code.  Hence, your question is still not reproducible.  Does your ANOVA formula include `+ 1`?

Comment: This is my code: `anova3 <- aov(Alz_20 ~ Aalter + Ajp40 + Aalter*Ajp40, data=data3)`    what do you mean with +1?

Comment: SS can be calculated in 1 of 3 ways. Which way is it calculated in the methods you used? Depending on your data, one of those three measures is better suited than the other two. Since the partial eta squared is .01 for the interaction & the variables independently are at no effect and .03 (solid medium effect), it renders that high repeatability of that interaction & `Aalter` moot. Repeatability—that's your *p*-value. Your data is telling me one could confidently repeat the research & get similar results, the interaction and the var`Aalter` do not explain the variance in the dependent variable

Comment: the way I calculated it is type 1, but no table function allows type 1, only type 2 and 3... Do you know by any chance an anova table function which displays the results in type 1 SS?